# Azure DevOps pipeline how set vcvars64.bat then call msbuild.exe from batch file?

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-pipelines

On a local machine, I execute my **build.bat** after opening a **x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019**, then **build.bat** calls **msbuild.exe**.

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
build.bat
```

How can I do same in an Azure DevOps pipeline CmdLine task?

The **build.bat** call to **msbuild.exe** fails when called from azure-pipelines.yml **CmdLine** task.

Is there a reliable method to locate and call vcvars64.bat so that msbuild.exe can be found?

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'build.bat calls msbuild'
  inputs:
    script: |
      build.bat
```

Azure pipeline error:

```
2022-05-06T15:42:53.3802703Z 'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
2022-05-06T15:42:53.3803010Z operable program or batch file.
```

Thanks in advance for any tips or direction.

Comment: You'll need to specify the path to `msbuild.exe` inside your file, or provide a parameter/variable with path in your yaml file and pass it to your batch file.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, using batch file is out of DevOps philosophy. Instead, you should decompile your batch file to steps and then use appropriate DevOps step. for example, in case of msbuild this is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=azure-devops

But if you need to use msbuild directly, then you can use paths same like in your local env, but path to VS will depends on what version (agent pool) you using in your pipeline